# RAM related errors on a CentOS server

Tags: memory, centos-6, syslog

I am getting a series of what appears to be RAM related errors on a server. Are these something to worry about? This is being used for scientific computation, is there a risk of data corruption that is undetected?

```
Message from syslogd@heracles at Dec  2 13:03:03 ...
 kernel:[Hardware Error]:   MC4_ADDR: 0x0000004603048430

Message from syslogd@heracles at Dec  2 13:03:03 ...
 kernel:[Hardware Error]: Northbridge Error (node 4): DRAM ECC error detected on the NB.

Message from syslogd@heracles at Dec  2 13:03:03 ...
 kernel:[Hardware Error]: cache level: L3/GEN, mem/io: MEM, mem-tx: RD, part-proc: RES (no timeout)

Message from syslogd@heracles at Dec  2 13:05:33 ...
 kernel:[Hardware Error]: CPU:32 MC4_STATUS[-|CE|MiscV|-|AddrV|-|-|CECC]: 0x9c01400004080a13

Message from syslogd@heracles at Dec  2 13:05:33 ...
 kernel:[Hardware Error]:   MC4_ADDR: 0x000000460304c070

Message from syslogd@heracles at Dec  2 13:05:33 ...
 kernel:[Hardware Error]: Northbridge Error (node 4): DRAM ECC error detected on the NB.

Message from syslogd@heracles at Dec  2 13:05:33 ...
 kernel:[Hardware Error]: cache level: L3/GEN, mem/io: MEM, mem-tx: RD, part-proc: RES (no timeout)

Message from syslogd@heracles at Dec  2 13:14:18 ...
 kernel:[Hardware Error]: CPU:32 MC4_STATUS[Over|CE|MiscV|-|AddrV|-|-|CECC]: 0xdc15400054080813

Message from syslogd@heracles at Dec  2 13:14:18 ...
 kernel:[Hardware Error]:   MC4_ADDR: 0x0000004603048430

Message from syslogd@heracles at Dec  2 13:14:18 ...
 kernel:[Hardware Error]: Northbridge Error (node 4): DRAM ECC error detected on the NB.

Message from syslogd@heracles at Dec  2 13:14:18 ...
 kernel:[Hardware Error]: cache level: L3/GEN, mem/io: MEM, mem-tx: RD, part-proc: SRC (no timeout)
```

Comment: Have you tried to do a memtest to see if your RAM are fine?

Comment: This question has already been answered here:  http://superuser.com/questions/502269/hardware-error-messages-from-syslogd

Comment: The error seems different to the last time you asked this, I don't see a mention of the ECC error being corrected. I would run a memtest to make sure the memory isn't causing issues.